# Check if integer is a key in keyboard

Tags: java, swing, key, keystroke

I am new to java swing. I have a problem in checking whether a integer acquired in Database is a valid key in keyboard.

Is there some built in function that returns true or false if int is a valid keycode?

Something like this

KeyEvent.getKeyText(119);
= F8 (so it is true)

KeyEvent.getKeyText(134319);
= Unknown (so it is false)

Thanks!

Comment: public static boolean functionThatReturnsTrueOrFalseIfIntIsAValidKeycode(int a) {
        return !java.awt.event.KeyEvent.getKeyText(a).startsWith("Unknown keyCode:");
    }

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for a method that returns true if the key code is a key *on the user's keyboard*, right? For example, if I'm using a compact keyboard with no home key, then the method would return false for `KeyEvent.VK_HOME`. (It would be fairly easy to write, say, a method that simply returns true if the specified keycode is one of the codes defined by the `KeyEvent` class, but it sounds like that's not what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

You can look inside KeyEvent class' source code, and notice that when executing the *getKeyText(int keyCode)* method, if no match is found then a particular value will be calculated and returned, creating it with a default concatenation: just do the same control and check if invoking getKeyText() on your code does return that value.

I just tested this and it seems to work:

```
public static boolean isValidCode(int keyCodeToCheck) {
        String unknown = Toolkit.getProperty("AWT.unknown", "Unknown");
        return !KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCodeToCheck).equals(unknown + " keyCode: 0x" + Integer.toString(keyCodeToCheck, 16));
}
```

Hope this can help you, have a nice day :)